# usage of the phrase "intrinsic nature of the philosophy"

Tags: grammaticality

I am trying to use the phrase *"intrinsic nature of the philosophy"* in the following sentence, which comes from my thesis writing. As an ABC learner, I am not quite sure whether this expression is lengthy. Could someone give me a hand to make the following sentence an elegant English writing. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

> This issue is more intractable, as the flaw is rooted in the *intrinsic nature of the philosophy*.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage—Stack Exchange! As per our [faq], proofreading questions, unless they specify the exact point of concern, are off-topic here.

Comment: I have refined my question. Could this post be reopened?

Comment: As per the FAQ, you cannot replace your question with "delete, delete, ..." or similar things becuse our goal is not only to provide you an answer, but also to minimize the time you have to wait for deleting the question: the community will decide on this.

Comment: John Smith — please read the [faq]. This question is ostensibly proofreading. That is off topic for the site. If you change your question to frame your doubts clearly, there might be something salvageable.

Comment: John, you may wonder, why is this considered proofreading?  Well, you haven't explained a few things, like: (a) Where did that quote come from?  A book?  Or did you make it up? (b) What might be wrong with the use of that phrase? Does it seem out of context? Are you hung up on one particular word? In short, you need to be much more specific about what you are asking, from a language perspective. Don't pose this as a question that could be answered with a simple "yes" or "no" – which is where it stands as I'm writing this comment.

Comment: Why did I get -2 ? It seems that closing this question is again too hard.

Comment: If the question is refined as requested, when will the post be opened again?

Comment: It takes 5 vote-to-reopen votes to reopen a question. I don't know if your question will get reopened, but, I will say this: based on the information provided, the sentence seems fine as is.

Comment: I agree with @J.R.; sometimes, it is helpful to search whether a particular combination of words is acceptable, but in your case the sentence is well structured as it stands.

Comment: ... however you might be interested to improve your question. Since, as it seem, your doubts are related to lengthness, I suggest you to ask: "Is there a word to define the 'intrinsic nature of the philosophy'?".

Comment: Lengthiness is a subjective quality in English, so people will disagree about whether something is too lengthy or not. Since this is subjective, this kind of question is not a good fit for EL&U (since it's not about grammar but more writing style), and would work better on writers.stackexchange.  However, to answer your question, "intrinsic nature of the philosophy" is nowhere near being convoluted enough to be considered too lengthy.